# What could be the reason for this issue in my css?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

I currently have built a form a form-field(pull down menu) and a button. The only issue I have run into is when I try to create another pull-down menu below the first it messes up my original pull-down menu by throwing the info out of the box. Can someone please take a look a see what I'm exactly doing wrong cause I'm not really sure why its happening.

```
<?php
$shows = array( "Sesame Street on Ice", "The Wiggles Live", "Dora Live" )

$prices = array( 29.99, 35.49, 49.95, 34.99, 9.99 );

?>


<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
background: tan;
font-family: arial;
}

#contentwrap {
background-color: white;
border: 6px darkred solid;
padding: 110px;
width: 600px;
margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
border-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
}

#heading {
color: darkred;
font-size: 2.2em;
padding: 0px 0px 19px 0px;
margin: -70px -90px 5px -90px;
text-align: center;
}

#content {
height: 220px;
padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
}

#border {
color: lightblue;
border-bottom: 8px double;
padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
margin: -85px -80px 10px -80px;
}

#border2 {
color: darkred;
border-bottom: 8px double;
padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
margin: 180px -80px 0px -80px;
}   

.formtext {
color: lightblue;
margin: -280px 0px 0px -50px;
}

.formtext2 {
color: lightblue;
margin: -10px 0px 0px -50px;
}

.formfield {
padding: 0px;
font-size: 1em;
width: 250px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px -50px;
color: black;
border: 2px darkred solid;
background-color: lightyellow;
border-radius: 4px;
}   

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="contentwrap">

<div id="heading">Online Order Event Form</div> 

<div id="border"></div>

<div id="content">

<div id="border2"></div>

<div class="formtext">Choose a show</div>
<select class="formfield" name="Show">


<div class="formtext">Select a number of tickets (max 4)</div>
<select class="formfield" name="Tickets">


<?php
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $shows ); $i++ ) {

        echo "<option value=\"". $i ."\">". $shows[ $i ] 
            ." $". $prices[ $i ] ."</option>\n";
    }

?>


</select>

<div style="margin:160px 0px 80px -48px;">
    <input type="submit" value="Order Tickets" />
</div>

</form>



</div> <!-- ends div#contentwrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: SELECT "Tickets" is nested within SELECT "Show" ... first, fill "Show" with options and close it. Then, start next SELECT.

Comment: alright I'll start there thanks

Comment: The only difference is I'm using an array to populate the data like what I have above. The first box works great but the second pull down menu never shows up at all. All it does is push the info for the first pull-down out.

Comment: You should grab the rendered html and css and build a repro on jsfiddle

Comment: You should build up an IRC proxy in order to use it as a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has loads of `<div>` tags but no corresponding closing `</div>`.
There's also a `</form>` with no corresponding `<form>`.

Also consider using indentation for easier reading.

Edit: Okay, so it's something to do with your CSS and usage of `margin` to try and position things.